# How to Hide Next-Auth Credentials Provider 'Sign in with Credentials' Option

Tags: next.js, jwt, next-auth

I have a secondary Next-Auth CredentialsProvider that is called programmatically to update / mutate session data if a session attribute is changed (User Role, in my case).

I'd like to hide that Sign-In option on the Sign-In page since it is only ever called programmatically.

Is there a way to hide a CredentialsProvider Sign-In option?

There is not much documentation on updating / mutating session data so I'm not really sure if there will be documentation on hiding CredentialsProvider Sign-In options but would appreciate any if you know of it.

Comment: It should be possible to do so. Here's the section of the documentation about it: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization#advanced-initialization (see last code snippet). Which is based on the following GH discussion: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/3133#discussioncomment-1600196.